# nav-bar for mobile not working in bootstrap

Tags: html, mobile, bootstrap-4, menu

My menu works perfectly on a PC but when it shows on mobile i can click and it will go away as if its taking me somewhere but then nothing happens ... not sure what is happening can someone please lend me a hand

also had to post my code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

here this is my current code

```
<head>
      
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>apis Sanctum</title>
 
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bg.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/image-effects.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
       <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="css/component.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css">
      
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
      
 
  </head>

  <body>
     <div class="container page-styling">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="site-name">
        <img src="img/title1.png" alt="" class=""><img src="img/title2.png" alt="" class="">
      </div>



<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Menu Bar --------------------------------------------------------------------->



      <div class="menu">
        <div class="navbar">
         
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown ">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown">About<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/MISC/BEES/euro_honey_bee.htm">Apis Mellifera</a></li>
                <li><a href="Sanctum_Way.html">The Sanctum Way</a></li>
                <li><a href="construction.html">Sanctum Alvarium</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown ">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown">News<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="Blog.html">Buzz Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com/search?biw=2560&bih=1292&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ACYBGNSmV-AkRf4x_HTd8CxClP41MOAg0A%3A1571337867589&ei=i7aoXZbAI8645gKwqbrIBQ&q=Honey+Bee&oq=Honey+Bee&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.7127.7127.0.8117.1.1.0.0.0.0.285.285.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.284....0.Fa7EiqCeuBY">Bee News</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown ">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown">Donate<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="construction.html">Donate</a></li>
                <li><a href="construction.html">Join Our Cause</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->

          </div>
          <div class="mini-menu">
            <label>
          <select class="selectnav">
            <option value="#" selected="">Home</option>
            <option value="#">About</option>
            <option value="http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/MISC/BEES/euro_honey_bee.htm">→ Apis Mellifera</option>
            <option value="Sanctum_Way.html">→ The Sanctum Way</option>
            <option value="construction.html">→ Sanctum Alvarium</option>
            <option value="#">News</option>
            <option value="Blog.html">→ Buzz Blog</option>
            <option value="https://www.google.com/search?biw=2560&bih=1292&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ACYBGNSmV-AkRf4x_HTd8CxClP41MOAg0A%3A1571337867589&ei=i7aoXZbAI8645gKwqbrIBQ&q=Honey+Bee&oq=Honey+Bee&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.7127.7127.0.8117.1.1.0.0.0.0.285.285.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.284....0.Fa7EiqCeuBY">→ Bee News</option>
            <option value="#">Donate</option>
            <option value="construction.html">→ Donate</option>
            <option value="construction.html">→ Join Our Cause</option>
            <option value="Contact.html">Contact</option>
          </select>
          </label>
          </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```